# I don't want "rake install" to publish to Rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm running:

```
rake install
```

on a project built with `bundle gem <project_name>`

I've published the gem to Rubygems. However, sometimes I'm on a VPN and I don't want `rake install` to try to also publish the gem to Rubygems.

I just want it installed locally.  How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

The rakefile created by bundler will not publish your gem when you run `rake install`.

You are thinking of `rake release` Don't forget that you can do `rake -T` to see a list of all described tasks.

```
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.0.21


$ bundle gem somegem
      create  somegem/Gemfile
      create  somegem/Rakefile
      create  somegem/.gitignore
      create  somegem/somegem.gemspec
      create  somegem/lib/somegem.rb
      create  somegem/lib/somegem/version.rb
Initializating git repo in /Users/joshuajcheek/deleteme/somegem


$ cd somegem
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 staff    91B Feb 12 22:00 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--  1 staff    28B Feb 12 22:00 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x  4 staff   136B Feb 12 22:00 lib/
-rw-r--r--  1 staff   793B Feb 12 22:00 somegem.gemspec


$ rake -T
rake build    # Build somegem-0.0.1.gem into the pkg directory
rake install  # Build and install somegem-0.0.1.gem into system gems
rake release  # Create tag v0.0.1 and build and push somegem-0.0.1.gem to Rubygems


$ mate . # removing TODOs from the .gemspec


$ rake install # notice this is not pushing to rubygems
somegem 0.0.1 built to pkg/somegem-0.0.1.gem
somegem (0.0.1) installed


$ gem list somegem

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

somegem (0.0.1)


$ gem search -r somegem # does not show up in rubygems list

*** REMOTE GEMS ***
```

Comment: i noticed a problem while on company vpn, rake install would hang, so i assumed it was publishing.  there is still an issue with rake while on vpn...don't know what it is...

Comment: Perhaps someone added dependent tasks to install, you should be able to see with `rake install --trace`